# Nsattributedstring with different NSMutableParagraphStyle

Tags: ios, attributes, nsattributedstring

I have 1 attributed string with multiple paragraph.
I had given the `FirstLineHeadIndent = 2.12.`
Now I want to give the `FirstLineHeadIndent=0` to 1st paragraph
and `FirstLineHeadIndent=2` to 2nd paragraph in the attributed string.

If I set the property like

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing =Line_space;
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent =2;
        paragraphStyle.headIndent =margin_space;
        paragraphStyle.tailIndent =-margin_space;
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing=paragraph_space;

        NSDictionary *ats = @{
                              NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:self.bookView.defaultFontFamily size:self.bookView.defaultFontSize],
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                              };
```

It will give the  head space to both the paragaraph.
Please help me.
I am uploading the image for more help:- [image]

Comment: How did you set the paragraph style to your `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: @Larme I had set the paragraph style by NSMutableParagraphStyle.But it gives imapact to all the paragraph.I want to set different style to 1st and 2nd paragraph.For example 1)paragraph have line space =2 and 2nd paragraph have line space =4.

Comment: Could you show all the code?

Comment: NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent =2;
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing=paragraph_space;

        NSDictionary *ats = @{
                              NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:self.bookView.defaultFontFamily size:self.bookView.defaultFontSize],
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                              };

Comment: You need to use 2 paragraphStyle, with different range. Is that what you do?

Comment: Can you give me example? how do i fetch the range of the 1st paragraph? It is not always fix? Do you any idea to fetch the range of paragaph dyanamically?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what you have, and what you want? An illustration could be useful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52667/discussion-between-shweta-and-larme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the solution is to use 2 paragraph styles.
Your `NSString` is separated by a `\n`, that indicate the separations between the 2 paragraphs.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *firstParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[firstParagraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:0];
//Do the rest of the settings

NSMutableParagraphStyle *secondParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[secondParagraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:2];
//Do the rest of the settings

//You may use the same paragraphStyle, changing just the firstLineHeadIndent, and set the attributes, but for a clearer explanation, I used 2 paragraph styles
NSRange range = [[yourAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"\n"];

[yourAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: firstParagraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)]; //The range is from the start to the \n

[yourAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: secondParagraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [[yourAttributedString string] length]-range.location)]; //The range is from the start of \n to the end
```